# Sitecore Powershell get rendering parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, sitecore, rendering

Using Sitecore Powershell, I'm trying to get a rendering parameter called "Form Id". I was heading this route, but it is wrong. What is the best way to return a specific parameter?

```
$device = Get-LayoutDevice -Default
$renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $item -Device $device -FinalLayout 
Get-Rendering -Item $item -Device $rendering -Parameter @{FieldName ="Form Id"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters will be available as a query string as part of the rendering itself.

```
$rendering = Get-Rendering -Item $item -Device $rendering
# (Presuming this returns one rendering only)
$dict = [Sitecore.Web.WebUtil]::ParseQueryString($rendering[0].Parameters)
$parameterValue = $dict["FormId"]
```

Note that Sitecore doesn't allow setting rendering parameter names with spaces in them.

Comment: The $rendering[0].Parameters is working but the parsing for some reason doesn't appear to be working. When I write host I get $[Sitecore.Web.WebUtil]::ParseQueryString Form Id=1234&Floodlight Code&Success Message&Redirect URL. $dict doesn't seem to populate.

Comment: Got it to work. I had to remove the $ sign in the line $[Sitecore.Web.WebUtil]::ParseQueryString.

Comment: Re parameter names with spaces in them, I'm able to do that successfully in v9.3 with passing the parameters as a hashtable.